# Uncaught exception testing GET resource

Tags: node.js, express, testing, jestjs

I have a small project [here](https://github.com/elirandav/node-alpha/blob/master/tests/users.test.js) and I created simple test:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const bodyParse` = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
    .use(bodyParser.json());

require('../routes')(app);

test('users',async () => {
    await request(app)
        .get('/users')
        .expect(200);
});
```

When I execute `npm test` I get:

```
 No tests found in tests/users.test.js
 1 uncaught exception
```

`npm test` defintion in `package.json`: `"test": "ava tests/**"`

Any idea why do I get exception instead of "test passed"?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a stack trace in that output as well, I get this:

```
❯ npm t

> alpha-node@0.0.0 test /private/var/folders/2_/qczp184x76b2nl034sq5hvxw0000gn/T/tmp.PCqu6DgMB6/node-alpha
> ava tests/**



  ✖ No tests found in tests/users.test.js

  1 uncaught exception

  Uncaught exception in tests/users.test.js

  /private/var/folders/2_/qczp184x76b2nl034sq5hvxw0000gn/T/tmp.PCqu6DgMB6/node-alpha/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635

  TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

  node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
  next (node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:210:14)
  Function.handle (node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
  router (node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
  Object.<anonymous> (tests/users.test.js:8:1)
```

The exception is preventing the tests from running.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I edited the question - I copied the test from a project that use jest and not ava. node testing beginner here. The goal is to test the GET resource `users`. I saw the exception, do you know what is the proper way to use `express` to not get this error?